# How to remove from generic doubly linked list

Tags: java, generics, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to build a remove function to remove a particular organ from the list.
I get an error of NullPointerException
I would like to know what my mistake is.
Why am I getting this error.
Thanks.

> A method to delete a specific organ. The method returns the deleted organ, organ lab is not on the list, it returns null

```
import java.util.ListIterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class LinkedListDouble<T> {
    private LDNode<T> head;
    private LDNode<T> tail;
    public int size;


LinkedListDouble(){
    this.head = null;
    size = 0;
}


public void add(T item){ // add item to the list
    if(head == null ){
        head = new LDNode<T>(item,null,null);
    }
    else{
        LDNode<T> n = new LDNode<T>(item, null, null);
        while(n.next != null ){
            n = n.next;
        }
        n.next = new LDNode<T>(item,n,null);
    }size++;
}

public T remove(T item){ // remove item from the list
    T ans=null;
    LDNode<T> n = head;
    int i=0;

    while(n.data != item){
        n = n.next;
        i++;
    }
    if(i == size) return null;
    if(n == head) {
        ans = head.data;
        head.prev.next = head.next;
        head.next.prev = head.prev;
        head = head.next;
    }
    else {
        ans = n.data;
        n.prev.next = n.next;
        n.next.prev = n.prev;
    }
    size--;
    return ans;

    }

public int size(){
    return size;
}
```

**Node:**

```
public class LDNode<T> {
T data;
LDNode<T> next,prev;


LDNode(){
    next = null;
    prev = null;
    data = null;
}

/*LDNode(T data){
    this(data,null,null);
}*/
LDNode(T data , LDNode<T> next , LDNode<T> prev){
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
    this.prev = prev;
}
LDNode(LDNode<T> Other){
    this.data = Other.data;
    this.next = Other.next;
    this.prev = Other.prev;
}

T getData(){
    return data;
}

public void setNextNode(LDNode<T> next){
    this.next = next;
}
public LDNode<T> getPrevNode(){
    return prev;
}
public void setPrevNode(LDNode<T> prev){
    this.prev = prev;
}
public void setData(T data){
    this.data = data;
}
public LDNode<T> getNextNode(){
    return next;
}
```

}

**Main:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedListDouble<Integer> itay = new LinkedListDouble<>();
    itay.add(1);
    itay.add(2);
    itay.add(3);
    itay.add(4);
    itay.add(5);
    itay.add(6);
    System.out.println(itay.size());
    itay.remove(1);
    System.out.println(itay.size());
}
```

**Error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at Matala2.LinkedListDouble.remove(LinkedListDouble.java:45)//head.prev.next = head.next;
at Matala2.LinkedListDouble.main(LinkedListDouble.java:78) //itay.remove(1);
```

Comment: Either `head` is `null` or `head.prev` is. `head` cannot be, or you would have got the exception one line earlier. So `head.prev` is null, so you r attempt to assign to `head.prev.next` gives NPE.

Comment: What had you expected that `head.prev` should have referred to? Without studying every line in your code, I would have expected it to be `null`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

The first foreseen problem is in the `add` method of the `LinkedListDouble` class. See, you're creating `head` and after that don't link it with any other instance of the `LDNode` class. So, `head` always have `null` as `prev`, that's why you're getting NPE. Moreover, a code inside the `add` method never places any different from `null` as `prev` value of `LDNode` object. Consider revising your `add` method of the `LinkedListDouble` class.